# Instruments Time Profiler Multiple Symbols Named "Main Thread"

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, instruments

I've noticed while running time profiler in Instruments that I get multiple symbols named "Main Thread".

Is there not supposed to be only one main thread and then what is this other thread called _____NSThread_______main_____ ?

[image: Time Profiler Main Threads?]